# Listing Scholar-Athlete Awards in Grad School Application

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, awards

I am a student athlete (Full scholarship) and I have received Scholar Athlete award from NCAA and my conference throughout my career. To receive these awards, your GPA should be 3.5 or more. Now I am applying for MS in Computer Science and they have a section:

> Summary of Honors, Scholarships, Fellowships, and Awards Received
>   During Your Academic Studies

Should I include the scholar athlete awards in this section and if it will hurt or better my chances? Can i also write that I received full scholarship for playing sports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would include the awards and emphasize how your experience as a student athlete reflects your time-management skills and ability to perform well under stressful circumstances.  You also capitalized on a great opportunity-- funding via a scholarship-- and made the best of it.

By the way, computer science is one of those fields in desperate need of diversity-- as an academically strong athlete, you would be offering a unique perspective.  Don't be shy about what you're good at, and why the program would benefit from your presence.